# Finding highest score in one array and matching that index to another array's index

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

was wondering if someone might be able to look at my program. I need assistance in finding out how to populate a dynamic array, whose size is a counter that increments when a condition is satisfied, and how to find the highest double in that array. Thank you all!

Here is the problem: 
Write a program that takes in N scores and finds each contestant's score
1. Enter N (for number of judges that will be giving a score)
2. Enter contestant id
3. Find the average from those scores (find max and min, subtract them from total to divide by N-2)
The program should do this until a contestant id entered is invalid (negative numbers).
This is what I have thus far.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
double average(int N, int scores[])
int main()
{
    int N, id, contestants = 0, return_scores = 0;
    int scores[10];
    int *contestant = new  int[contestants];
    double *avg_scores = new  double[contestants];
    double avg;
    int highest, index;

    cout << "Number of Judges: " << endl;
    cin >> N;
    cout << "Enter ID: " << endl;
    cin >> id;
    if (id >= 0)
    {
        contestants++;
    }
    while (id >=0)
    {
        //populate the contestants array with id if id is valid
        for (int i = 0;i < contestants;i++)
        {
            contestant[i] = id;
        }


        cout << "Enter scores:" << endl;
        for (int i = 0;i < N;i++)
        {
            cin >> scores[i];
        }

        //call function to calculate average
        avg = average(N, scores);
        for (int i = 0;i < contestants;i++)
        {
            avg_scores[i] = avg;
        }

        highest = int(avg_scores[0]);

        cout << "Contestant: " << id << " " << avg << endl;
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "Enter contestant ID: " << endl;
        cin >> id;
    }
    //find the index to the highest score and match it with the contestants array
    for (int i = 0;i < contestants;i++)
    {
        if (highest < avg_scores[i])
        {
            highest = int(avg_scores[i]);
            index = highest;
        }
    }
    cout << "Contestant: " << contestant[index] << " had the highest score.\n";
    return 0;
}

double average(int N, int scores[10])
{
    double total = 0;
    double min = scores[0], max = scores[0];
    double average = 0.0;
    double drop = min + max;
    //find the total/min/max
    for (int i = 0;i < N;i++)
    {
        total += scores[i];
        if (scores[i] < min)
        {
            min = scores[i];
        }

        if (scores[i] > max)
        {
            max = scores[i];
        }
    }
    //average
    average = ((total - min - max) / (N-2));
    return average;
}
```

Comment: What you have "thus far" is poorly indented, and somewhat unreadable. If you want to get some assistance with your program, the least you could do is to indent it properly, so that others can easily read it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post for how to ask better questions, which will help people give you better answers. As Sam mentions, proper indentation is very helpful in improving readability, and it's a very good habit to get into for your own code too!

Answer (score 0):

One rather serious problem in your code is at the beginning:

```
int N, id, contestants = 0, return_scores = 0;
int scores[10];
int *contestant = new  int[contestants];
double *avg_scores = new  double[contestants];
```

When you allocate your arrays, the above code allocates `contestants`
integers for the `contestant` array, and `contestants` doubles for
`avg_scores`. Unfortunately, `contestants` is zero, which means you're
allocating no memory at all. To make matters worse, you never re-allocate
any of those arrays, so your program has undefined behavior because
you're storing things in zero-length arrays.

You also have other problems, such as:

```
    for (int i = 0;i < contestants;i++)
    {
        contestant[i] = id;
    }
```

...which always wipes out every contestant ID you stored previously. You do the same thing to the average scores.

Also, you allow the user to specify the number of judges in the `N` variable, and then you read `N` score into the `scores` array. But for some reason, you declared `scores` as a fixed-length array that always has 10 elements. That means if I enter 11 as the number of judges, you'll write past the end of the array. You should dynamically allocate the `scores` array so it contains `N` elements.

For your contestant IDs and scores, it looks like you need to allocate some memory at first, and then
allocate additional memory as you read in more data, since you
have no way of knowing in advance how many contestants you are
going to read in. There are two ways out of this:

1. Ask for the number of contestants in advance, like you do with
   the judges. This is the easy way.
2. Increase the size of the `contestant` and `avg_scores` array
   as you read in more data.

I don't know which one is required by your professor, so I'll show
you option 2, since it allows you to preserve the basic structure of
your program. I'm assuming that using `std::vector` is prohibited.
That would be the *real* easy way.

Each array will require three variables:

```
int *contestant;
size_t contestant_capacity=0;
size_t contestants=0;
```

The reason for the extra variable is that you're going to allocate more
memory than you need, and then you'll allocate more only *if* you need to.
We need a function to add values to the array for us:

```
#include <cstring>

int *add_contestant_id(int *array, size_t *capacity, size_t *size, int id)
{
    if(*size == *capacity) {
            *capacity *= 2;
            int *new_array = new int[*capacity];
            memcpy(new_array, array, (*size)*sizeof(int));
            delete[] array;
            array = new_array;
    }
    array[(*size)++] = id;
    return array;
}
```

Putting it in a separate function keeps all this bookkeeping out
of your `main` function, making the main loop simpler and therefore
easier to understand.

You need another function just like it except with floats in order to add
a new score to the `avg_scores` array. I'd normally use a template to
avoid writing the same function twice but with different types, but you may not be allowed to do that. But if you were allowed, the code would look like this:

```
template <typename T>
int *add_value(T *array, size_t *capacity, size_t *size, T value)
{
    if(*size == *capacity) {
            *capacity *= 2;
            T *new_array = new T[*capacity];
            memcpy(new_array, array, (*size)*sizeof(T));
            delete[] array;
            array = new_array;
    }
    array[(*size)++] = value;
    return array;
}
```

Getting into the habit of splitting your code into functions is a good
idea. Breaking code into small pieces makes it easier to wrap your
head around the problem. When you read a contestant's ID, that should be
its own function:

```
int read_contestant_id()
{
    int id;
    cout << "Enter ID: " << endl;
    cin >> id;
    return id;
}
```

Then, your `while(id >= 0)` loop can be rewritten as:

```
for(int id=read_contestant_id(); id >= 0; id=read_contestant_id()) {
    ...
}
```

Reading the average score for a single player is also a good candidate for a
separate function (and a good place to dynamically-allocate the `scores` array):

```
double read_avg_score(int nJudges)
{
    int *scores = new int[nJudges];
    for(int i=0; i<nJudges; i++) {
            cout << "Enter scores:" << endl;
            cin >> scores[i];
    }

    double return_val = average(nJudges, scores);
    delete[] scores;
    return return_val;
}
```

After you rewrite your read loop to use these functions, the code
looks like what I have below. Notice how the whole `main` function now fits on the screen at once.

With all the serious bugs fixed, the only bug left
to fix is figuring out the difference between the highest score and
its index in the array, which should be easier now since the rest of the program actually does what you thought it was doing before:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

double average(int N, int *scores);
double read_avg_score(int nJudges);
int read_contestant_id();
double *add_average(double *array, size_t *capacity, size_t *size, double avg);
int *add_contestant_id(int *array, size_t *capacity, size_t *size, int id);

int main()
{
    int id;
    size_t N=0, contestants = 0, contestants_capacity=1; 
    size_t avg_scores_capacity = 1, avg_scores_size=0;
    int *contestant = new  int[contestants_capacity];
    double *avg_scores = new  double[avg_scores_capacity];
    double avg;
    int highest, index;

    while(N == 0) {
        cout << "Number of Judges: " << endl;
        cin >> N;
        if(N == 0) {
             cout << "You can't have ZERO judges." << endl;
        }
    }
    for(int id=read_contestant_id(); id >= 0; id=read_contestant_id())
    {
        // populate the contestants array with id, which is ensured to be
        // valid by the for-loop invariant.
        contestant = add_contestant_id(contestant, &contestants_capacity, &contestants, id);

        // Read the scores, calculate the average, and populate the avg_scores array.

        avg_scores = add_average(avg_scores, &avg_scores_capacity, &avg_scores_size,
                                 read_avg_score(N));
    }
    //find the index to the highest score and match it with the contestants array
    for (int i = 0; i < contestants; i++)
    {
        if (highest < avg_scores[i])
        {
            highest = int(avg_scores[i]); // <-- Maybe highest should be a double.
            index = highest; // <-- Here's where you made the mistake.
        }
    }
    cout << "Contestant: " << contestant[index] << " had the highest score.\n";
    return 0;
}

double average(int N, int *scores)
{
    double total = 0;
    double min = scores[0], max = scores[0];
    double average = 0.0;
    double drop = min + max;
    //find the total/min/max
    for (int i = 0;i < N;i++)
    {
        total += scores[i];
        if (scores[i] < min)
        {
            min = scores[i];
        }

        if (scores[i] > max)
        {
            max = scores[i];
        }
    }
    //average
    average = ((total - min - max) / (N-2));
    return average;
}


double read_avg_score(int nJudges)
{
        int *scores = new int[nJudges];
        for(int i=0; i<nJudges; i++) {
                cout << "Enter scores:" << endl;
                cin >> scores[i];
        }

        double return_val = average(nJudges, scores);
        delete[] scores;
        return return_val;
}

int read_contestant_id()
{
    int id;
    cout << "Enter ID: " << endl;
    cin >> id;
    return id;
}


int *add_contestant_id(int *array, size_t *capacity, size_t *size, int id)
{
        if(*size == *capacity) {
                *capacity *= 2;
                int *new_array = new int[*capacity];
                memcpy(new_array, array, (*size)*sizeof(int));
                delete[] array;
                array = new_array;
        }
        array[(*size)++] = id;
        return array;
}

double *add_average(double *array, size_t *capacity, size_t *size, double avg)
{
        if(*size == *capacity) {
                *capacity *= 2;
                double *new_array = new double[*capacity];
                memcpy(new_array, array, (*size)*sizeof(double));
                delete[] array;
                array = new_array;
        }
        array[(*size)++] = avg;
        return array;
}
```